# Flex item won't consume available space in container when second flex item introduced

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container named `#center` in which I want to display `canvas` and a `button` inside it. I want the `canvas` object to take all the available space (respecting the button inside the container).

This is my code:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.block {
  flex: 1;
}
#left {
  background-color: green;
}
#center {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
#right {
  background-color: orange;
}

#canvasObject {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="block">Left</div>
  <div id="center" class="block">
    <canvas id="canvasObject">Your browser does not support Canvas.</canvas>
    <button type="button">Click!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="block">Right</div>
</div>
```

If I do not have any `button` in my code, `canvas` occupy the full `div` but when I display the `button`, `canvas` does not seem to resize the desired `height`.

- [Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/9j1ddeLb/): Without button.
- [Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/9j1ddeLb/1/). With button.

How can I make that the `canvas` object will resize until the available `height` (also `width` but it is already doing it)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `align-content: flex-start` on a row-direction flex container:

```
#center {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
    align-content: flex-start;    /* <-- source of the problem */
}
```

The `align-content` property controls the spacing between flex items in the cross-axis when there are *multiple lines in the container*.

When the `button` element is excluded, there is only one line in the flex container. In such a case, `align-content` has no effect (`align-items` would work).

But when you add the button, there are now two lines on wrap, and `align-content` takes over (`align-items` does not work).

Since `align-content` is set to `flex-start` in your code, both lines are packed to the top of the container. (For other options, try `flex-end`, `center`, `space-between`, `space-around` and `stretch`).

An efficient solution would be to use `flex-direction: column` and apply `flex: 1` to the `canvas`.

```
#center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;        /* new; stack flex items vertically */
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
    /* align-content: flex-start;  <-- remove; not necessary */
}

#canvasObject {
    flex: 1;                        /* new; consume all available free space */
    /* display: block;              <-- remove; not necessary */
    /* margin: 0 auto;              <-- remove; not necessary */
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

### [**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9j1ddeLb/4/)

---

W3C References:

- [8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
- [8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the `align-items` and `align-self` properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)